# OpenGL ES texture is shifted with the same code as in OpenGL version

Tags: ios, opengl-es

In my Windows code (OpenGL 4), I have this to calculate texture position in Fragment shader:

```
vec2 pixel = "some equation"
vec2 textureSize = vec2(512.0, 512.0);
vec2 texel = floor(pixel + vec2(0.5)) + vec2(0.5);
texel /= textureSize
```

If I run this code on iOS (OpenGL ES 3.0), my entire image is partialy shifted in x and y direction. I have tried to remove `vec2(0.5)` and just use

```
vec2 texel = floor(pixel + vec2(0.5))
```

but it was even more incorrect.

What is going on in ES?

Comment: Based on your shader I suspect the problem is in "some equation."  Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - questions with half the required data missing are impossible to answer. Screenshots with the error vs expected behavior would be useful too ...

Answer (score 1):

Presumably shader precision. Try adding:

```
precision highp float;
```

at the top of your fragment shader.

Without that statement, and in the absence of precision qualifiers on individual vars, then your maths operations may (depending on the implementation) take place with half precision floats rather than single precision (16-bit floats instead of 32-bit floats), and that lack of precision could explain the artifacts you're seeing.

Note that OpenGLES implementations are free to not support highp in fragment shader, so this approach may not work everywhere. However, it is supported on all iOS devices, which is all you mention.

Comment: Tried that, with the same result

Comment: It's an odd texture size. Is it possible that during texture loading it gets padded to a 1024x1024? That would throw things out significantly.

Comment: Texture is 512x512. I have updated quetsion. I have written there screen resolution, instead of texture.